# How can I create an automation script in Google Scripts but with a changing url and entries?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm looking to create a script to automatically submit a golf booking on Google Forms. The script works fine, but the problem is that the `form_url` always changes daily. The contents of the form will never change, it is just a new `form_url` with the same questions. It is time consuming to change the code daily with the new `form_url` and its respective entries in the variable `datamap`, that the use of the script becomes redundant.

```
function golf_booking() {
  
  var form_url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdYIVdqE7ifKk9gyhtDssK__7Pa9s91n3LwTyAXEdxQe72lRA/formResponse";
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet = workbook.getSheetByName("Details");
  
  var email_address = worksheet.getRange("B1").getDisplayValue();
  var player_1 = worksheet.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue();
  var membership_1 = worksheet.getRange("B3").getDisplayValue();
  var mobile_number = worksheet.getRange("B4").getDisplayValue();
  var booking_date = worksheet.getRange("B5").getDisplayValue();  
  var booking_type = worksheet.getRange("B6").getDisplayValue();
  var preferred_time = worksheet.getRange("B7").getDisplayValue();
  var player_2 = worksheet.getRange("B8").getDisplayValue();
  var membership_2 = worksheet.getRange("B9").getDisplayValue();
  var player_3 = worksheet.getRange("B10").getDisplayValue();
  var membership_3 = worksheet.getRange("B11").getDisplayValue();
  var player_4 = worksheet.getRange("B12").getDisplayValue();
  var membership_4 = worksheet.getRange("B13").getDisplayValue();
   
  var datamap = {"emailAddress" : email_address,
"entry.216124446" : player_1,
"entry.30938407" : membership_1,
"entry.414700871" : mobile_number,
"entry.1525670783" : preferred_time,
"entry.1547640370" : player_2,
"entry.1456486255" : membership_2,
"entry.1990389779" : player_3,
"entry.345335083" : membership_3,
"entry.623638002" : player_4,
"entry.1777567375" : membership_4,
"entry.1886384367" : booking_date,
"entry.1951022441" : booking_type};
  
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : datamap
  };
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(form_url, options)
  
}
```

I'm wondering if someone might have an idea about how to either:

1. Automatically fetch the new `form_url` and its entries for the `datamap` variable.
2. Maybe, create a `for` loop to post the responses to the questions in sequential order?

Comment: Have you ever considered using a Web app?

Comment: Why does the form URL change daily?

Comment: I'm also wondering why the form URL changes daily. Is it because the URL you are trying to get is the form response URL?  Then it isn't updated daily, but is unique for everyone submitting the form response response. Also, how do you define these keys in your datamap? Where do you find the entry numbers?

Comment: @ Cooper: What web app do you know of? The form url changes daily by the author who publishes the form. It is not possible to ask them to stop changing the form url.

Comment: @ NaziA The author of the form will publish a new form with the same questions daily, so presently it takes more time to locate the url and its entries. The entry numbers are found after I inspected the form they published and selected each entry and see its number.

Comment: I am quite baffled with this one. Sorry. Unless there is a pattern in the daily url, which is highly unlikely, this seems impossible within the range of my skills.

Comment: Why and how is the author pushing a new form every day? Are you using the responses spreadsheets? The author could click Responses and 'use existing spreadsheet' every time they do whatever and all responses would be in one place.